# Can a Multivariate Normal Distribution be used as a Bayesian Prior?

Tags: regression, bayesian, estimation, maximum-likelihood

Suppose you have a regression model : Y = B_0 + B_1 * X

If you wanted to perform Bayesian Linear Regression, this would require you to place priors on "B_0", "B_1" and "Sigma".

I have seen people place priors on each of these 3 terms as (independent) univariate Normal Distributions. For example:

- Prior on "B_0" = Normal(mu_1, sigma_1)
- Prior on "B_1" = Normal(mu_2, sigma_2)
- Prior on "Sigma" = Normal(mu_3, sigma_3)

These priors can then be multiplied by the joint likelihood, and the MAP estimates of  "B_0", "B_1" and "Sigma" can be calculated (e.g. either via theoretical conjugacy properties or MCMC sampling).

**My Question:** Instead of the above approach where 3 different independent univariate normal distributions were used as priors - could the likelihood be multiplied by a trivariate normal distribution containing a mean vector as well as a specific type of variance-covariance matrix?

Is this an acceptable approach?

Thanks!

Comment: A normal prior on $\sigma,$ which cannot be negative, makes no mathematical sense.  Although such a prior could be used (provided is assigns near-zero chance to negative values), the next question concerns how to specify the covariance matrix of all three parameters.  It is implausible that you would have the information to do that in a reasonable manner.  If you leave $\sigma$ out of the question, though, one might be able to imagine situations in which prior information on the correlation of the $\beta_i$ is available.  For instance, that information could come from a previous regression.

Comment: @ whuber : thank you for your reply! Could you try this instead: place a log normal prior on sigma, and place a bivariate normal distribution on beta_0 and beta_1? Would this address the problem you indicated? Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, it would, although it would be simpler to place an inverse gamma prior in $\sigma$ (it is a conjugate prior, permitting easier calculations).